# Please solve the heat equation satisfying the neumann condition of zero flow at the infinite boundary

Tags: partial-differential-equations, proof-writing, problem-solving, heat-equation

The equation is
\begin{equation}
\left\{\begin{aligned}
&\frac{\partial N(t,x)}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial ^2 N(t,x)}{\partial x^2}&x\in \Bbb R\\
&N(0,x)=N_0(x) &x\in \Bbb R\\
&\lim_{x\to +\infty}\frac{\partial N}{\partial x}=\lim_{x\to -\infty}\frac{\partial N}{\partial x}=0.
\end{aligned}\right.
\end{equation}
Is the solution of above equation only a constant? If so, how to prove it?

Could someone help me see the next step? I'm stuck.

Comment: Is $\Vert N_0\Vert _2$ finite?

Comment: Yes,  if we assume that $||N_0||_2< \infty$, do you have any ideas?

Comment: Given that I think the solution is the same as the Dirichlet ($\lim_{|x|\to\infty}N(t,x)=0$) case

Comment: In fact the finite 2 norm might not even be necessary because of the growth estimate condition